# Import / Export Workflow using StsAdm

Tags: workflow, migration

I have migrated a site from one server to another - both running MOSS 2007.

The bulk of the site transferred correctly, but I did have to manually edit some custom display forms.

The 4 workflows are my main concern. They did come across to the new site, but they're not working correctly. When I try to load them in Sharepoint designer (on new site). I get an error message "Failed to load workflow".

Any ideas on how to go about fixing the workflows?

It appears to me that the listID's are that of the old site, and these ID's have changed with the import, am I right? Adjusting the ID's might be a good starting point.

Comment: How did you migrate the site? Was there no option for retaining the IDs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The safest way that I've seen to "migrate" SharePoint Designer workflows is to just recreate them manually after the lists have been migrated.  They just don't port very well.

If your workflows were created in Visual Studio, then it would be as simple as re-deploying the solution containing the workflows.  Sorry there's not a better answer for SharePoint Designer.