# How do I split a 2007 sharepoint collection that has a large number of SPD Workflows

Tags: workflow, migration

Our site collection is growing rapidly and we would like to split it into a number of new collections.

Our concern is that when we secure a number of sites and recover them into the new collection, all workflows are lost.

ARe there any ways of splitting the collection which will preserve/migrate the workflows without us having to recreate them all - there are over 400 workflows in total over about 160 sites in the collection. The collection is about 60GB in size and we would like to end up with 5 collections each of which would need to have workflows migrated to it.

Thanks

Dave

Comment: Yikes.. thinking out loud.. Aren't workflows tied to the specific sub-site and not the site collection? However, I found [this question/answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/6818/import-export-workflow-using-stsadm) which doesn't make it look good.

Answer (score 1):

You can migrate SharePoint Designer workflows from one site collection to another using the CodePlex SharePoint Workflow Migrator.